# Preventing measure from being affected by visual filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to stop this measure from being affected by visual filters:

```
DIVIDE(
   CALCULATE(
       COUNTROWS('Table1'), 
         FILTER('Table1', 'Table1'[column1]="High")),
         COUNTROWS('Table1'))
```

I have tried adding the ALL function after the COUNTROWS and FILTER function but this did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, removing `CALCULATE` and just using ALL as a table function that ignores any existing filter context should work

```
DIVIDE(
    COUNTROWS( FILTER( ALL( 'Table1' ), 'Table1'[column1] = "High" ) ),
    COUNTROWS( ALL( 'Table1' ) )
)
```

In case you need to satisfy slicers, you might use `ALLSELECTED` instead of `ALL`

Comment: Whilst this doesn't throw any errors, when using it on a line chart over a 12 month period, the value being returned from the measure is just the percentage over whole 12 month period rather than the percentage for each month which is the desired outcome

Comment: Yes, since it removes any existing filter coming from the visuals, as asked. Can you please change the question in order to ask what is the expected result? Do you have a Date column? And a Date table?

Comment: Sorry sergiom, this question wan't very clear. I have added a new question which is different to this one as this is the problem I am now faced with: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734156/showing-average-percentage-for-whole-department-and-average-percentage-for-indiv

Comment: Also, there is no separate date table