# Showing average percentage for whole department and average percentage for individual on line chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to display the average percentage for all 'excellent' case outcomes over the 12 month period for all colleagues on a line chart. I want this line to be unaffected by the colleague name filter on the visual.

This is some sample data from the 'case' table:

[image]

This is the measure I have so far:

```
Excellent Fixed = 
   CALCULATE(
     COUNTROWS('Case'), 
      FILTER('Case', 'Case'[Case Outcome]="Excellent"),
       ALLEXCEPT('Case', 'Case'[Date].[Month])) / 
   CALCULATE(
     COUNTROWS('Case'),
       ALLEXCEPT('Case', 'Case'[Date].[Month]))
```

On the line chart visual, the 'Axis' is set to Date - Month and the 'Values' has the 'Excellent Fixed' measure as shown above. This correctly displays the average Excellent cases over the 12 month period but the visual **is** affected by the colleague name filter (i.e when selecting John Smith from the colleague name visual filter, the visual changes to just show the average for that colleague. Also, I have noticed that the average then being displayed for that colleague is incorrect).

The expected result should be that the measure is unaffected by the 'colleague name' visual filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is the `FILTER` over the table `'Case'`

Since the `'Case'` in the current filter context is sliced per `Collegue Name` and therefore it re-inserts the filter removed by the `ALLEXCEPT`

A possible solution is to change the FILTER with a filter argument on the single column `Case Outcome`

```
Excellent Fixed =
DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS( 'Case' ),
        'Case'[Case Outcome] = "Excellent",
        ALLEXCEPT( 'Case', 'Case'[Date].[Month] )
    ),
    CALCULATE( COUNTROWS( 'Case' ), ALLEXCEPT( 'Case', 'Case'[Date].[Month] ) )
)
```

Comment: Can I ask another question if possible? Why would you use the FILTER function rather than just use filter arguments like you have done above? Also, If I wanted to set multiple filter arguments (I.e. I wanted to show all Excellent and Great case outcomes), how would I do this in the above measure?